# Как обойти все файлы в папке и подпапках и прочитать текстовые файлы в массив?

Tags: java

Мне нужно поочередно считать текст из текстовых файлов (.txt), которые находятся в папке и сохранить в array.

Пример:

```
                    Корневая Папка
                /         |         \
        Папка А       Папка Б     Папка В 
      /    |    \     / | \      /    |    \ 
 1.txt  2.txt  3.txt  . . .  n-2.txt  n-1.txt  n.txt
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это реализовать.

Comment: Давайте разобьём на три простых вопроса: (1) Дан каталог, как обойти все файлы и подкаталоги в нём; (2) Дан текстовый файл, как прочитать его содержимое в строку, и (3) Дана строка, как записать её в массив.

Comment: VladD, спасибо!

Comment: Рано говорить спасибо :) Но сейчас вы можете структурировать вопрос, и получить на него хороший ответ.

Comment: @VladD, мне кажется, что хороший ответ здесь получить всё же не получится, ввиду того, что ТС просит написать программу за неё.

Answer (score 18):

Давайте попробую ответить в меру своего понимания.

(1) Обход файлов. Есть два способа — традиционный и простой, и модный и прикольный, но сложный.

Традиционный способ заключается в применении рекурсии:

```
public void processFilesFromFolder(File folder)
{
    File[] folderEntries = folder.listFiles();
    for (File entry : folderEntries)
    {
        if (entry.isDirectory())
        {
            processFilesFromFolder(entry);
            continue;
        }
        // иначе вам попался файл, обрабатывайте его!
    }
}
```

Модный метод — применение Streams API:

```
Files.walk(Paths.get("ваш каталог тут"))
     .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
     .map(Path::toFile)
     .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Или если вам нужны только пути, то просто

```
Files.walk(Paths.get("ваш каталог тут"))
     .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
     .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Применяйте, если для вас слово «лямбда» означает больше, чем название греческой буквы.

(2) Чтение файла в строку. Применяйте вот какую конструкцию:

```
byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
String content = new String(bytes, encoding);
```

При этом вы, понятно, должны знать кодировку файла (вы ведь понимаете, что текстовый файл без кодировки — нонсенс?). В качестве возможных кодировок — `StandardCharsets.UTF_8` для UTF-8. Ну или может подойти `Charset.defaultCharset()`.

(3) Ну и по поводу записи в массив есть своя тонкость. Когда вы обходите каталог, вам неизвестно, сколько файлов в нём окажется. Поэтому вы не можете выделить под них массив нужного размера. Поэтому лучше собирать данные в список (например, `ArrayList<T>`), который умеет автоматически расти.

И работать по сути тоже лучше со списком. Если тем не менее вам понадобится именно массив, можно сконвертировать список в массив, например, так:

```
String[] array = list.toArray(new String[0]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Всё просто.

Первым делом обойдите все поддиректории и файлы в них. Итератор, например, можно взять из [FileUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#iterateFiles%28java.io.File,%20org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.IOFileFilter,%20org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.IOFileFilter%29) (или оттуда же listFiles, смотря что нужно).

Считайте каждый файл в строку. Собственно, [нужные методы](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readFileToString(java.io.File,%20java.nio.charset.Charset)) тоже есть в FileUtils.

Добавить в массив каждую строчку, надеюсь, проблемы не составит.